# How to make azure functions v2 load assembly from bin folder and not from the host bins?

Tags: azure-functions

I have a dependency on my code for an old keyvault package

If I in my function checks what it loads:

```
var a = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(Path.Combine(assemblyFolder, "Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.dll")));
```

I see that it loads 3.0.0 and not 1.0.0 - and also it's loaded from

`AppData/Local/AzureFunctionsTools/Releases/2.24.0/cli/Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.dll`

and not the bin folder of my function output
`... \bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\bin\`

How do I tell my function project to use the dlls in the output bin?

Not that the assembly load stuff is only to debug what is going on. My client code fails later due to assembly versions 1.0.0 and 3.0.0 are not compliant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the code as below:

```
var binPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
string dll = Directory.GetFiles(binPath, "Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories)[0];
Assembly loadedAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile(dll);
```

The snapshot:
[image]

Comment: Sorry, could not get it working. It started throwing other exceptions when trying to load the dll. I used v1 framework instead and got things working there.